# Error setting property on CLLocation subclass

Tags: iphone, exception, subclass, core-location

I've defined this subclass of CLLocation

MyLocation.h

```
@interface MyLocation: CLLocation {
    NSString *datum;
    NSString *ellipsoid;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *ellipsoid;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *datum;
```

MyLocation.m

```
@synthesize datum,ellipsoid;
```

Now I get a CLLocation instance through the location manager delegate

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    //self.myPosition is a MyLocation myPosition;
    self.myPosition = newLocation;
    [myPosition setDatum: @"WGS 84"];
    [myPosition setEllipsoid: @"WGS 84"];
}
```

When I do the `self.myPosition = newLocation`, I get an UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION and it dies

I've also tried this way with same results:

```
self.myPosition = (MyLocation *)newLocation;
```

Answer (score 0):

newLocation is not an instance of ur subclass so doing that assignment or casting throws an error because it's an invalid cast, u should be seting the values of ur subclass that u want fromthe cllocation object something like

```
self.myPosition=[[MyLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate]
```

and so on